# Suppose g is open and t continuous. Is f(z)=g(z)(1+t(z)) an open map?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, open-map

Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ be given. Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous, open mapping and suppose $t:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function such that $|t(z)|<\varepsilon$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Define $g(z)=f(z)+f(z)t(z)$. Is it true that $g$ is an open map also?

Intuitively I believe this to be true, for since $f$ is open and $g$ is a 'small' variant of $f$ and so no ball can collapse under the mapping $g$. However I am struggling to show this computationally. I have tried showing this from definition but keep getting lost in the algebra. Here I have been considering $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the Euclidean norm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f = \mathrm{id}$ and $t$ is the constant function $t(z)=0$, then $z \mapsto f(1+t(z))$ is constant, hence is not open. But $f$ is open and $t$ is continuous

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. If you're saying $f=id$ and $t=0$, then wouldn't $g$ just be $f$ and so necessarily open?

Comment: Letting $t(z) = - 1$ will fix the counterexample.

Comment: How about if $\varepsilon<1$? Would such an example still exist?

Comment: Actually, what does it mean for $1 + t(z)$ since $t(z) \in \Bbb{R} ^2$?

Comment: Sorry I have just edited, I was intending for it to mean when multiplied out you have your original function plus a 'small' function multiplied by the original function

Comment: @George Sorry I misread. I thought you wanted the composition to be open, not the product.

Comment: Should $t$ map to $\mathbb R^1$?

Comment: I was viewing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$, so no. The map $t:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.